# MS Access pull down column via query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the following table in MS Access:

```
   ID | column1 | column2           | column3                
   ---+---------+-------------------+--------------
    1 | A       | Publishers        | Publishers
    2 | 01      | Commercial        |  
    3 | 02      | University Press  |  
    4 | B       | Place             | Place 
    5 | 01      | United States     |  
    6 | 04      | Western Europe    |  
    7 | 05      | Other             |  
    8 | C       | Language          | Language  
    9 | 01      | English           |  
   10 | 02      | French            |
```

I am looking for the following result

```
   ID |column1  | column2           | column3                
   ---+---------+-------------------+--------------
    1 | A       | Publishers        | Publishers
    2 | 01      | Commercial        | Publishers
    3 | 02      | University Press  | Publishers
    4 | B       | Place             | Place 
    5 | 01      | United States     | Place 
    6 | 04      | Western Europe    | Place 
    7 | 05      | Other             | Place 
    8 | C       | Language          | Language  
    9 | 01      | English           | Language  
   10 | 02      | French            | Language
```

So basically pulling down column3 heading. I have tried searching the net and asking other pals with some ms access knowledge. But really couldn't find any "pull down" query. Copy/paste wouldn't suffice as this will be performed many times in a day and with much larger data set. Can this be done without vba (looking to get this done through a query)?

Comment: Unless you have a column that specified the ordering, you will need to do this in the application.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets and there is no obvious ordering on these rows.

Comment: Not to open a whole can of worms here, but is it possible for you to break your table into separate tables, i.e. `Publishers`, `Places`, `Languages`? It looks like you are trying to maintain multiple lists in one table, which is contrary to most good database practices.

Comment: Also, is your goal to retrieve the data in the form you show in the second listing (in which case you're asking us for a query), or to update the data in the first listing to match the second listing?

Comment: Finally, assuming you're stuck with the data in this layout, can you promise that all the publishers, places, and languages are grouped together (no mixing of publishers and languages, say) and that the IDs will always be sequential (no missing numbers) and ascending?

Comment: @Ann L.  I am stuck with this data. I am unable to break it (full table is a very long table). I am retrieving data. Yes it will always be sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select column1, column2,
       (select top (1) t2.column3
        from t as t2
        where t2.id <= t.id and
              t2.column3 is not null
        order by t2.id desc
       ) as column3
from t;
```

Comment: I created a table with auto-increment. Your query is giving a syntax error

Comment: @Wsi . . . Well, that is rather vague.   It is not clear what might be causing such an error.

Comment: it was (1). I tried query without it like select top 1, and no syntax error. But the query didnt work. It didnt pull down column 3 unfortunately

Comment: @Wsi . . . This query should bring in the most "recent" non-`NULL` `column3` value up to each row.